# How to obtain a twitter api access token in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to convert a Python app I made some years ago to a (better) NodeJS implementation. The function in question obtains an access token from the Twitter api to attach to future requests, but my implementation returns 403 bad request. Here is a the functional Python implementation..

```
def get_bearer_header():
    uri_token_endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
    key_secret = f"{twitter_creds.CONSUMER_KEY}:{twitter_creds.CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET}".encode('ascii')
    b64_encoded_key = base64.b64encode(key_secret)
    b64_encoded_key = b64_encoded_key.decode('ascii')

    auth_headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(b64_encoded_key),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        }

    auth_data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        }

    auth_resp = requests.post(uri_token_endpoint, headers=auth_headers, data=auth_data)
    bearer_token = auth_resp.json()['access_token']

    bearer_header = {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(bearer_token),
        'oauth_consumer_key': twitter_creds.CONSUMER_KEY 
    }
    return bearer_header
```

and here is the JS implementation so far..

```
export const getBearerHeader = async () => {
    const keyAndSecret = btoa(`${config.twitterApi.consumerKey}:${config.twitterApi.consumerKeySecret}`)
    const buff = Buffer.from(keyAndSecret, 'utf-8');
    const b64KeyAndSecret = buff.toString('base64');
    const body = new URLSearchParams({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    })
    const url = config.twitterApi.oauthTokenEndpoint
    const headers =  {
        'Authorization': `Basic ${b64KeyAndSecret}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    }

    const resp = await axios.post(url, body, headers)
    console.log("RESPONSE.data")
    console.log(resp.data)
}
```

the request looks fine according to twitter docs, but my response says 403!

Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Twitter access token v2 by python and node.js code.

To create [API Key and Secret](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/overview) from
[Twitter Developer Portal](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard)

Main idea to use curl commend for getting access token.
[POST oauth2/token](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/token)

Using config.json file

```
{
    "API_KEY" : "Xx7MxxxxxTkzxxxxxq9xxxxxQ",
    "API_KEY_SECRET" : "om4QxxxxxPrcPlxxxxxFikDxxxxxoC5mQxxxxxLy7M17xxxxxK"
}
```

Node.js code

```
const axios = require('axios')
const config = require('./config.json');

const getAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
            'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
            '',
            {
                params: {
                    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
                },
                auth: {
                    username: config.API_KEY,
                    password: config.API_KEY_SECRET
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

getAccessToken();
```

python code

```
import requests
import json
import ast

def get_access_token():
    with open('config.json') as config_file:
        data = json.load(config_file)

        params = {
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        }

        response = requests.post('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', params=params, auth=(data['API_KEY'], data['API_KEY_SECRET']))

        print(response.content)
        json_data = ast.literal_eval(response.content.decode("UTF-8"))
        return json_data['access_token']


print(get_access_token())
```

run from terminal
[image]

Comment: the documentation was telling me to encode to b64 and what not which i did originally and it worked. amazed that this (simpler) solution works, thanks!

Comment: any idea why my node version does work? have they updated the api the last few weeks? or does axios automatically b64 encode the body? I am confused as to how the implementations could be so different but still work

Comment: I did not know, twitter API history. I just implemented both language from Twitter web site [POST oauth2/token](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/token). I use [curl to other language online service](https://curlconverter.com/)